# chipsets supporting BLE peripheral role on Android 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

The new BLE peripheral mode introduced by Android 5.0 (Lollipop) won't be enabled on the Nexus 4, 5, or 7 (https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1570#c52), but will be enabled on the Nexus 6 and 9.

Even though the Bluetooth 4.0 compliant chipsets in the Nexus 4/5/7 should support both Central and Peripheral modes, Android 5.0 has singled out the Peripheral advertising function by adding the boolean call "BluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()".

As an example, this code will show that advertisement is not supported on a Nexus 5, but that it is supported on a Nexus 9.

```
BluetoothManager btMgr = (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter btAdptr = btMgr.getAdapter();

if (btAdptr.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()) {
    Log.v(TAG, "advertisement is SUPPORTED on this chipset!");
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "advertisement NOT supported on this chipset!");
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml should at least have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

Whenever I look up a chipset I only see that it "supports Bluetooth 4.0" and no distinction is made between Central and Peripheral support.  Is there a way to tell which Bluetooth chipsets would support Peripheral mode on Android 5, without running the above code or having access to their firmware source?

Comment: I don't think that the question is too broad. It's a simple yes or no question and if yes, how to do it. I would also be interested in this so that's why I'm commenting.

Comment: Apart from Nexus 6 & 9, are there any other devices which support peripheral role?

Comment: Hey I just got a Moto E 4G LTE and verified that it supports the peripheral role.

Comment: @ludwigmace have you tried the MOTE G serials which shipped with Android 5? I can't get a Moto E 4G in my country.

Comment: I can't find exactly what provides the Bluetooth on that phone, but looking at the specs, the non 4G version has the same Qualcomm Snapdragon 200 processor as the Moto E 1st gen.  That leads me to believe Peripheral mode wouldn't be supported.